# Insert data in response of Message class in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, response, iis-10

I need to insert in a response information in the body of this with c#.

Currently I have a function that inserts a custom message in an HttpResponseMessageProperty object which is validated from the web client observing response.statusText.

When accessing from https we discover that this data is not being sent since the requests are being made from http \ 2.

Instead of how we are sending it, I would like to know in what way I could send that data through the body.

The following code works with http 1.1. And response is of class Message

```
if (message.Length > 0) {
     property.StatusDescription = message
}
response.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = property;
```

Later that Message object is returned through RequestContext Reply.

How can I include data that I can later read from response.data in javascript?

Thank you all

EDIT:

I'm using Net Framework 3.5

Comment: A standard way of replying with a bunch of information is to use the JSON format. Whatever framework you're using, I'm sure it provides that option. Reading it back in JS is simple: `fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).then(response => { ... });`

Comment: Thank you, however that part does not generate doubts. The problem is how to insert that data into the body of a C # Message instead of how we are currently entering it

Comment: I think you can use response.Body.WriteAsync() and  Response.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue() to insert data into reponse body in asp.net.

Comment: Thanks, but this way it also changes the status to written and that prevents me from sending the message later since it was modified.